# TypeScript inferring recursive type not as expected

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference, recursive-type

I expect the `InferTest_1` type can be applied recursively because the inferred type variable `NSuc` is expected to be type `Nat`, but typescript complains that `NSuc` does not satisfy the constraint `Nat`. But when I try to apply `InferTest_1` with type `Two`, typescript actually can achieve what I expected: `Zero` (since what type `InferTest_1` do is to recursively unwrapping `Suc`'s type)

But the type `InferTest_2` shows that `NSuc` can extends `Nat`. And `InferTest_3` shows that typescript can actually infer the `Suc` type, as `T2` is inferred to be type `One`. So what is the key point behind that? is this related to lazy evaluation ?

```js
  type Zero = {tag: 'Zero'};
  type Nat = Zero | {tag: 'Suc'; Suc: Nat};

  type One = { tag: "Suc"; Suc: Zero };
  type Two = { tag: "Suc"; Suc: One };


  type InferTest_1<N extends Nat> = 
     N extends Zero
     ? Zero
     : N extends {tag: 'Suc'; Suc: infer NSuc} 
      ? InferTest_1<NSuc>  // Error: Type 'NSuc' does not satisfy the constraint 'Nat'. Type 'NSuc' is not assignable to type '{ tag: "Suc"; Suc: Nat; }'.
      : never;

  type T0 = InferTest_1<Two> // {tag: 'Zero}

  type InferTest_2<N extends Nat> = 
    N extends {tag: 'Suc'; Suc: infer NSuc} 
     ? NSuc extends Nat 
      ? true
      : false
     : never

  type InferTest_3<N extends Nat> = 
    N extends {tag: 'Suc'; Suc: infer NSuc} 
     ? NSuc extends Nat 
      ? NSuc
      : false
     : never
  
  type T1 = InferTest_2<Two>;  // true
  type T2 = InferTest_3<Two>;  // { tag: "Suc"; Suc: Zero }
  type T3 = T2 extends One ? true : false; // true
```

Comment: `InferTest_1<NSuc & Nat>` will fix it.

Comment: Yes! this will fix.  Answer below shows that there is a more simple way to fix. But ultimately, this seem to be related to this issue I just find. [#23132](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23132)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `infer` here, as the type of `Suc` is known

```
type InferTest<N extends Nat> = 
  N extends Zero
  ? Zero
    : N extends {tag: 'Suc'; Suc: Nat}
    ? InferTest<N['Suc']>
    : never;
```

Comment: This look nice!